# How to get selection start/end for spans using JS?

Tags: dom

I have contenteditable span with different styles inside of it. So it's not a plain text.

```
<span contenteditable="true">One <span style="color:red;">two</span> three</span>
```

I need to get selectionEnd and selectionStart of a selected area.

The selected area can possibly include spans with different styles:

[image]

I've read about Selection and Range of course but can't understand how to use them for this task.